# Fipy Get values from a mesh region and not by point coordinates

Tags: fipy

I am trying to get values from a region. I know that there is a method to call the values by introducing the coordinates:

```
var([(x1, x2, x3) #xvalues
     (y1, y2, y3)]) #yvalues
```

But, for instance, it is confusing to how many points and which coordinates they have if I previously set the values by using the 'where' attr in var.setValue (which accepts regions).

```
var.setValue(20., where=(Y <= y1) & ((X <= x1) & (X > x2)))
```

Is there any method to get the values by "querying" a region as in the var.setValue(where='...')?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's possible to construct a mask for a region from the cell coordinates then that mask can be used to extract the values. There is no special function in FiPy to do this, but we can use a boolean mask to index into the variable. For example,

```
from fipy import CellVariable, Grid2D

mesh = Grid2D(nx=4, ny=4)
var = CellVariable(mesh=mesh)
mask = (mesh.y <= 2) & (mesh.x <= 3) & (mesh.x > 1)
var.setValue(20., where=mask)
print('x:', mesh.x[mask.value])
print('y:', mesh.y[mask.value])
print('val:', var[mask.value])
print(var.mesh)
print(var[mask.value].mesh)
```

gives

```
x: [1.5 2.5 1.5 2.5]
y: [0.5 0.5 1.5 1.5]
val: [20. 20. 20. 20.]
UniformGrid2D(dx=1.0, nx=4, dy=1.0, ny=4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(var[mask.value].mesh)
AttributeError: 'unOp' object has no attribute 'mesh'
```

This above gets you the sub-region of values along with the corresponding coordinates. However, there is no way in FiPy to extract a sub-region variable that also maintains its associated mesh data.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is simpler than mine:

`mesh = Grid2D(Lx=Lx, Ly = Ly, nx=nx, ny=ny)
X,Y = mesh.cellCenters

mask = ((Y <= y1 ) & (X <= x1))
mask_cells = [i for i in range(len(mask)) if mask[i]]

val = var.value[mask_cells]`